# Как установить интерпретатор PyPy для PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, pypy

Установил PyPy с официального сайта (PyPy.org), прислали архив, распаковал. Обычно, для добавления нового интерпретатора, просто указываю на exe-шник, но в этот раз постоянно выдаёт ошибку (`C:\Users\minerin\pypy3.10-v7.3.15-win64\pypyw.exe: can't open file C:\Users\minerin\\udccf\udcee\udcf0\udcf2\udcf4\udcee\udceb\udce8\udcee\telegrambot\test.py: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`). В самом архиве куча разных exe-шников, перепробовал разные, ошибка остаётся той же. Пожалуйста, помогите.

Comment: Проблема в пути к test.py. Перенесите его в каталог без русских символов в пути.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy спасибо большое, сработало

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy можете подсказать? В архиве с PyPy много разных exe файлов, для чего они предназначены и какой выбрать?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/x2en4f/please_help_me_choose_pypy_exe_for_interpreter_in/ или задайте отдельный вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Убрать кириллицу из пути файла